# How to find exact bounds of an application content using jna?

Tags: java, jna, screen-resolution, bounds

I couldn't able to find bounds of an application content.

I'm trying to move mouse to an exact location on the application content using java. For this purpose I need to find location on the application window. Used application for this process has `1024x768` bounds.

This is how I use `GetWindowRect`:

```
User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
HWND hWnd = user32.FindWindow(null, "A Random Application");
user32.ShowWindow(hWnd, User32.SW_SHOW);
user32.SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

RECT bounds = new RECT();
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hWnd, bounds);
```

However, I get following for the `bounds`:

```
[(445,141)(1475,938)]
```

This means window has `1030x797` resolution and it includes border of the window. I need to find where the application content starts(not the window's start point)? How can I achieve that?

**Note:** When I use `GetClientRect` I get `[(0,0)(1024,768)]`. But I can't get x and y.

Comment: Are you using swing for your application window?

Comment: Well sorry for misleading text, its an application which is not made by me.

Comment: That's too bad :( I can't achieve it either.

Answer (score 0):

`GetClientRect`'s return value is in client coordinates (relative to the upper-left of the client area).  You need to use [`ClientToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert client coordinates to screen coordinates -- specifically, converting (0, 0) from client to screen coordinates will tell you the upper-left of the client area relative to the entire screen.